# Views under RecyclerView not being displayed (only shows in Android Studio preview)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

This has been driving me nuts for a while now. I have a RecyclerView and a TextView below it. However, I can see everything above the RecyclerView but nothing below it.

Below is what my layout consists of, I just included the relevant codes

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:background="#f1f5f8"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/someTextView"

          />



<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/droid_serif"
            android:text="@string/browse"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have tried some approaches that I have found on the internet like replacing my original `ScrollView` with a `NestedScrollView` since my `RecycleView` scrolls horizontally but to no avail.

I have also tried adding this  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `RecyclerView` in the XML but also same output.

I would really appreciate any help as I have not found any case on the internet or SO like mine. Please note this is not the full layout file. There is other views above the `RecyclerView` but these are being displayed without any issue and hence I didn't put their codes. Let me know if there is any other information you need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try change your constraint layout to linearlayout (orientation vertical).
like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   >



         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:background="#f1f5f8"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/someTextView"

          />



          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/droid_serif"
            android:text="@string/browse"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set id "bottomTextView" for TextView that is below RecyclereView and
add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="bottomTextView"` for RecyclerView

Comment: share full code of your layout. also you can use RelativLayout insted of ConstraintLayout.